# split multi-dimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am trying to parse json data in ruby my desired output is:

```
var events = {  '01-01-2018' : 
                [ {content: 'Psalm 2',  allDay: true},
                  {content: 'by ToddWagner', allDay: true}
                ],
                '01-02-2018' :
                [ {content: 'Psalm 2', allDay: true},
                  {content: 'by ToddWagner', allDay: true}
                                            ]
                        }
```

what I get is

```
var events = [
                {"2017-11-03":
                        [ {"content":"Romans 14:5-12","allDay":true},
                          {"content":"by Micah Leiss","allDay":true}
                            ]
                        },
                {"2017-11-06":
                       [{"content":"Romans 14:13","allDay":true},
                        {"content":"by Sarah Thomas","allDay":true}
                        ]
                }
            ]
```

I tried something like

```
data = [] 
raw_data['entries'].each do |entry|
    data << {entry_date => [
                                {
                                  "content" => entry.title,
                                  "allDay" => true,
                                },
                                {                                                           
                                  "content" => entry.writer,
                                  "allDay" => true,
                                },
                            ]
                        }
end
data.to_json
```

but I didn't get desired results, I have also tried data.pop data.shift.

Comment: Do you want result to be a hash, or are there any other requirements?

Comment: Hash or array anything is fine

Comment: @SebastianPalma JSON input is from API all data are string.

Comment: try : data[entry.date] = [ ... ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby implementation would look like:

```
data = raw_data['entries'].map do |entry|
  [entry.date,  [entry.title, entry.writer].map do |content|
                  {content: content, allDay: true}
                end]
end.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are adding fields to your array `data`, as I can see from your desired output, you need a hash.

You have to create the hash, not the array:

```
data = {}
```

and then in your loop

```
raw_data['entries'].each do |entry|
```

add it like that

```
data[entry_date] = [   
                     {
                       "content" => entry.title,
                       "allDay" => true,
                     },
                     {                                                           
                       "content" => entry.writer,
                       "allDay" => true,
                     },
                   ]
```

(I am not where do you declare entry_date in your example so it might be entry.date)

I can't tell from your example if entry date is unique or not(and I think it's not) make sure you add to hash, because you might overwrite it.

You can do something like this if entry date isn't unique

```
data[entry.date] ||= []
data[entry.date] << {hash_you_need}
```

Comment: Abusing `each` with a previously declared local variable is a code smell. Use e. g. `each_with_object` instead. Also, to make a default hash element to be empty array, use `data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }`.

Comment: Thank you for advice @mudasobwa! Didn't know that:)